# How to make a rust-polars series List<64> from 2D ndarray?

Tags: rust, rust-polars, rust-ndarray

I have a 2-dimensional ndarray (`Array2<f64>`) of dimension `N x K` in rust.

I would like to convert this to a single polars series of dtype `List[f64]` i.e. every row will be a list of dimension `K`.

How can one accomplish this efficiently in polars-rust? I could convert the ndarray into e.g. `Vec<Vec<f64>>` by iterating across rows but am unsure how to proceed from there.

This is some sample code, with what I have tried so far, in case helpful:

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use polars::prelude::*;

let array: Array2<f64> = array![[1., 2.], [3., 4.], [5., 6.]];

let vec_of_vecs: Vec<Vec<f64>> = array
        .axis_iter(ndarray::Axis(0))
        .map(|row| row.to_vec())
        .collect();
// what to do now?

// *edit* this works, and does not require converting to vec of vecs first, but it is relatively slow

let chunked_list: ListChunked = array
        .axis_iter(ndarray::Axis(0))
        .map(|row| {
            Series::from_vec("", row.to_vec())
        }
         )
        .collect();
let series: Series = chunked_list.into_series();
```

Apart from going to polars dataframe then using polars expressions to create lists from the columns what is the most efficient path forward?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
let mut chunked_builder = ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder::<Float64Type>::new(
    "",
    array.len_of(Axis(0)),
    array.len_of(Axis(1)),
    DataType::Float64,
);
for row in array.axis_iter(Axis(0)) {
    match row.as_slice() {
        Some(row) => chunked_builder.append_slice(row),
        None => chunked_builder.append_slice(&row.to_vec()),
    }
}
let series = chunked_builder.finish().into_series();
```

In the best case (the data is continuously available) this allocates and copies the data only once. In the worst case, it does so twice (like your code), but it is always faster than your code (I benchmarked). The fast path will always be used if the array is an owned array (`Array2`) allocated using the default row-major layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply Chayim - quick benchmark for my data shows (dev-mode) a 25-30% speed up vs what I had!

Comment: @AzmyRajab Benchmarking in debug build is meaningless. Benchmark in release build.

Comment: Sorry - new to rust and didn't expect the level of optimizations that happen to be this meaningful. Below I report release build average timings over sample data:

Average execution time over 100 iterations: 177.13µs (before)
Average execution time over 100 iterations: 10.406µs (new - yours)

Thanks again :)